# what this error means :'The transaction is cancelled commands are ignored' in odoo

Tags: python, inheritance, odoo, boolean, many2one

I am working on odoo so I had to inherit a module and making some changes on it, so I had to create field that I called chauffeur which is many2one relation with rees.partner
and in my field I have to select only the drivers that have boolean=1.

but it returns to me this error:

> The transaction is cancelled, commands are ignored until the end of the transaction block

Can anyone please tell me what is the reason for this error and how to fix it?

my code:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api


class estChauffeur(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    bool_chauffeur = fields.Boolean('EstChauffeur', default=False)

 class suiviDesConstats(models.Model):
    _name = 'logistique.suivi.constats'

 chauffeur_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', comodelname='res.partner', 
 domain=[('est_chauffeur','=',True)])
```

Comment: Try editing your question and removing the duplicate code so it's simpler to read, it might help people help you.

Comment: @LucaBezerra hope it's more clear now?

Comment: don't forget that this is Python, you need to pay more attention to the indentation

Answer (score 2):

You are using non-existent `est_chauffeur` field, You need to check the Odoo log to get more details about the error.

you can try the below code:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api


class estChauffeur(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    bool_chauffeur = fields.Boolean('EstChauffeur', default=False)

class suiviDesConstats(models.Model):
    _name = 'logistique.suivi.constats'

    chauffeur_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Chauffeur', domain=[('bool_chauffeur ', '=', True)])
```